# Show or hide content based on the date with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to have some content on my page (some images) change based on the date. With jQuery, how would this be possible?

Basically, I am leaving on vacation and my client needs something to change while I'm unavailable.

I've been able to do it with ColdFusion for another client, but I don't know how to do it with jQuery. Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: It might be better to do this on the server side as any client could simply enable the change themselves if they knew to look for it.

Comment: Bryan, I would do it server side, but they don't use any server side technology... We're migrating their site to a new one shortly but it's a matter of propping this one up until the new site is ready. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example, check if Date is after Christmas.  The div_id needs to be set to display:none; initially.  You can change the selector to an id, class, or whatever else you need.

```
var now = new Date();

var Christmas = new Date("December 25, 2010");

if(now > Christmas) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div_id').show();
     // or a class of images
     $('.imageClass').show();
}
```

Comment: Great 11 line tutorial. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for Date object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

based on date just change/manipulate images